# Obtaining a circle packing from a set of circle centers?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, packing-problem

I want to grow circles centered at a set of $n$ points *simultaneously* and *uniformly* until a circle packing is created.

Is there a way I can solve for the radii of the circles in the packing analytically?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify. Show us some pictures of what you are looking for.

Without more restrictions there will be many solutions. You can see that with just three points. 

If you have four points consisting of two close pairs far apart any "packing" will consist of two pairs of tangent circles far apart.

Comment: @EthanBolker I want to grow circles uniformly from their centers until they touch. In that case, the solution should be unique, correct?

Comment: See [Koebe–Andreev–Thurston theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem)

Comment: Try to write a computer program where, as you say, you grow circles uniformly till they touch another one, see the problems, and only after that come back with your question...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yep, I've already written a computer program, and it works decently well if I make step size for growth small. My implementation is just very computationally expensive. Was wondering if there is a way to solve this problem analytically instead of numerically, that's all. Thanks!

Comment: Fine. I appreciate you have done that. Meanwhile, I have realized that you were not wanting a **close packing**. I have a solution to propose you (see my coming answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An essential technique for what you want to do is ["Delaunay triangulation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_graph) of your set of points. This will provide you the ["closest neighbour"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_graph) of a given point

Indeed, being given a certain point $V_1$; it is among the vertices of the Delaunay triangles having $V_1$ as one of their vertices that one finds another vertex $V_2$ which is at the shortest distance from $V_1$, a result that dramatically decreases the search time

Just a pitfall to avoid: "A has B for its closest neighbour" is not at all reversible: B can have another C as its closest neighbour.

I don't enter more into other details for the moment, but I can give more precisions (tomorrow: it's late now in Europe...).

Comment: This makes sense—thank you. I'll try implementing it.

Comment: In case of a problem, don't hesitate to ask...